# VNC keyboard and mouse login

Tags: windows, rdp, vnc, vnc-server

How does VNC forward remote keyboard and mouse events to the Windows login screen/prompt without having access to the desktop context? i.e. Does it use a custom driver to trick Windows into thinking that the mouse and keyboard are local?